# "And as a parent, that was my first thought" - is this wrong?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

(1)
And as a parent, that was my first thought: How is the kid doing, how are the families doing.”
(https://www.hcn.org/issues/52.11/south-education-in-las-vegas-the-burdens-of-remote-learning-rest-heavy-on-working-parents)

(2)
As a parent, that was something I was very grateful for.
(https://www.cantonrep.com/story/sports/2021/03/15/abbey-allerding-north-canton-hoover-ohio-high-school-girls-basketball-resigns/4708489001/)

These two sentences sound weird.

Isn't "as" supposed to refer to the subject when it is at the beginning of the sentence?

Like

> And as a parent, "I" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) And as a parent, that was my first thought: How is the kid doing, how are the families doing.”

> (2) As a parent, that was something I was very grateful for.

It is unusual to start a sentence with 'And'.  That aside, you are right that the main clauses of both examples should start with 'I'.

The 'that' in example 1 refers to the thought.  If it is used to start the main clause, it will be deemed modified by the prepositional phrase, resulting in misplaced modifier error.